# Numerical Solution to ODE with Jump Coefficients at Unknown Points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, continuity

I have a second order, non-linear ODE where the coefficients jump at a point depending on the solution itself. I have tried picard-type iteration with a simple upwinding scheme and dynamic mesh refinement, but both of these introduce their own errors specific to the problem.

A simple example looks like

$
a(x, y)y'' + b(x, y)y' + c(x, y)y = 0
$

where the coefficients vary smoothly except at some point $\alpha(x, y)$ which is part of the solution, $y$ is continuous, and where boundary values are given.

Does anyone know of references or have any ideas for how to solve this type of problem?

Comment: You have to be careful with this type of problem, since the usual existence and uniqueness properties may fail. You might look up "free boundary problem"

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm relatively confident about existence and uniqueness, as the solution looks correct but tends to blow up around the singularity. If I knew the location of the interface, the problem seems simple, but I only know within which cell it lies.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "tends to blow up around the singularity", that may not inspire confidence in existence and uniqueness.

Comment: By "blow up" I mean that a wave forms at the interface and propogates away. The function quickly changes its curvature right before the interface, making me think that this is driven by a numerical error, as the interface cuts the finite difference stencil at the surrounding nodes. I've been struggling to find a method that doesn't require exact knowledge of the interface location...

Comment: For an example of how things can go badly, you might look at 
$$ a(x) y'' = 0 $$
where $ a(x) = 2$ for $y \ge 0$, $-2$ for $y < 0$.   For $c > 0$, solutions $y = x^2 - c^2$ in the region $y > 0, x < -c$ and $y = - x^2 + c^2$ in $y < 0, x < -c$ meet at $x=-c, y=0$ and disappear (i.e. do not exist for $x > -c$), until they pop back into existence at $x = +c$.

Comment: That is very interesting. My problem actually arises from a financial model, so I'm pretty confident its solution should exist, although your comments are making me less and less sure. Do you have some references (textbooks) for these types of problems?